# Can I set a filegroup of database offline,change the location of files and bring it online again?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filegroups

I found that we can only take filegroup offline through t-sql,but to bring that filegroup online we need to restore the whole database.

Answer (score 7):

There is no T-SQL command to take a ***filegroup*** offline, though an individual ***file*** can be set offline.

From the documentation, [ALTER DATABASE File and Filegroup Options (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx):

[image: BOL excerpt]

> Use this option only when the file is corrupted and can be restored. A file set to `OFFLINE` can only be set online by restoring the file from backup. For more information about restoring a single file, see [`RESTORE (Transact-SQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx).

To relocate files, follow the [instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189133.aspx) in the documentation, or see the related Q & A:

[How do I move SQL Server database files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52007)