# I have changed sql db name from database.mdf to database_log.mdf and can't get access to it!

Tags: sql-server

I have encountered with a problem.
I was serfing the google how to change the mdf file location and found this post: 
[How do I move SQL Server database files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/how-do-i-move-sql-server-database-files).
But as it usually happens I did an error. I have used this code:

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE foo
MODIFY FILE (name='DB_Data1', filename='X:\NewDBFile\DB_Data1.mdf');
```

and modified DB_Data1.mdf to DB_Data1_log.mdf.
And now I can't attach this database to sql studio or open it in Visual Studio.
[image]
I need help please!

Comment: If you have logon permissions to the server, you have more options, like going to the D drive and changing the name back.   Do you have server access?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't.

Comment: I have solved this problem by giving to user "Anyone" full access to the .mdf  file in Security properties in Windows Explorer. As I expected security policy depends on some special user access rights. But I didn't find which system user profile could give such rights.