# Moving SQL Server Database Files to New Location - Why permission error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to move a database (`.mdf` and `.ldf` files) to a different directory on the same server hosting the SQL server.  I followed these steps found in [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/how-do-i-move-sql-server-database-files):

1. `ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`
2. `ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET OFFLINE`
3. `ALTER DATABASE MyDB MODIFY FILE (Name = MyDB, Filename = 'N:\DATA\MyDB.MDF')`
4. `ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET ONLINE`
5. `ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET MULTI_USER`

When I got to Step4, I got "Access Denied".  Unfortunately, my maintenance windows were very short and no time to troubleshoot.  So I decided to drop the database and restored it using the `WITH MOVE` clause to place the DB files in the right directory.  No issue.

My question is why did I get "Access Denied"?  I didn't change MSSQL service account.  It's the same account that ran the `RESTORE`.

Comment: This might answer your question [Access is denied error when attaching a SQL Server database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4542/access-is-denied-error-when-attaching-a-sql-server-database/)

Comment: Yes, I did move the files to the new location after I placed the db 'OFFLINE'

Comment: Also note that you're trying to move .mdf + .ldf whereas you run `MODIFY FILE` only for  .mdf

Comment: How did you move the files? The alter database command doesn't move the files--you need to manually move the files to the new location specified in the alter database command. Did you drag & drop in Windows Explorer? Use command line? Not do anything else beyond what you list above?

Answer (score 9):

The `ALTER DATABASE MyDB MODIFY FILE (Name = MyDB, Filename = 'N:\DATA\MyDB.MDF')` statement doesn't actually move the files.  It merely moves the *definition* of where the files reside.  You'd need to actually move the files manually before continuuing to step 4.

When you move the files prior to step 4, you must ensure the target directory has the correct permissions for the SQL Serve service account.  [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-ver15) details the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

A key point here is whether you moved or copied the database files. And if you "moved" the files between two different disks you actually *copied* them (there no such thing as moving a file between two disks even if commands/GUIs let you believe so).

Moving a file retains the owner and privileges on the file.

Copying on the same disk retains permissions but the owner of the new file will be the persons who did the copy.

Copying or moving a file to a different disk result in the person who does the copy/move becomes the owner of the new file. The old permissions is *not* retained.

What you see if common if you "move" a file between disks, and subsequently SQL Server won't have privileges on the new files. I.e., you need to set suitable permissions on the files to the SQL Server service account.