# How to change the files for a database through query?

Tags: sql-server

**Context:**
Running with SQL server 2017 on our environment. We have a different drive that holds various files related to the database like F drive holds the .mdf files (primary and audit) and H drive holds the .ldf file (log).

**Problem Statement:**
Due to a small mistake, the audit and log file swap its place and placed in alternate drive like the log files switched to F drive along with the primary file and the audit file moved to the H drive.

**Note:** The database is running fine and transactions are happening without any error, but want to rectify this as there are 80 databases on the server and this happened for only few like 12 databases.

**What I Tried so far:**
I tried to shut down the server and swap the files to the correct directories but didn't work.

Is there a way to rectify this from any query without shutting down the SQL server for some time as other team is going to affect by this?

Please refer to the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move SQL Server database files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/how-do-i-move-sql-server-database-files)

Comment: Have a look at MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-database-files?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DenisRubashkin yeah this answer my question