# SQL Server / SSMS taking up lots of disk space

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019, disk-space

I installed SQL Server + SSMS for my univ class and ever since then my disk space is going missing (every so often, approx. 3 gb of space goes missing). I strongly suspect SQL Server and/or SSMS to be at fault (since it only happened after I installed them), however I have no idea how to track down that missing space. Is it doing massive amounts of logging? Backups? No idea.

Where might I find that disk space and/or check if it is SQL Server's and/or SSMS' shenanigans?

Thank you for your time.

Note: I am using SSMS 18.9.1 and SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition. I might be able to update but any problems that arise will be my fault for deviating from the officially provided versions.

Comment: Yes, I did restore a database backup provided by the tutor.

Comment: I see the logs are tiny, I don't think they're the culprit behind my recent loss of disk space. I've set the logs to simple and shrank the file anyway, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to use [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) or [TreeSize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free) to see which files are actually taking up space. It may not even be what you think.

SQL Server doesn't take backups on its own, so it's unlikely those are the culprit unless you set them up via a maintenance plan or other script.

More likely is that:

- Your database is in full recovery and you're not taking log backups, in which case you can [switch it to simple recovery model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/view-or-change-the-recovery-model-of-a-database-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) so that SQL Server manages the transaction log a bit for you
- Your data/log files are set to grow by a percent, in which case you can [set them to grow by smaller more predictable increments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-ver15) so they don't grow by exponentially larger percentage-based increments

If the goal is to reclaim disk space, feel free to search for any number of scripts or GUI walkthroughs out there to accomplish that task.

Comment: Alas, it does look like SQL Server and SSMS might be innocent. While I did have a database set to Full Recovery, changing it to Simple did not return me my disk space. Still don't quite know what new stuff showed up - WinDirStat shows me stuff thats been there for a while, which means they're not the space-sucking newcomers I'm looking for.

Comment: @404NameNotFound if the database is in full recovery but you have never taken a backup it acts like it was in simple recovery anyway. It is only after you first back it up that the log file will start growing indefinitely

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit more work to set up, but even for laptop instances of SQL Server, I always make sure to [create a new drive](https://www.techadvisor.com/how-to/windows/partition-windows-10-3679598/) and set that as my default database file location. Since you've already installed SQL Server, you'd want to follow guidance for [changing the default database location](https://sqlandme.com/2013/03/18/sql-server-changing-default-database-location-for-server/).

If you've got databases already deployed that you cannot lose, then you may want to [move the database files to a new drive](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52010/68127) once you have it set up.

Note this will not stop SQL Server from filling the drive, but it will contain the damage to that drive and protect you from [a full C:\ drive](https://superuser.com/questions/182893/is-it-bad-to-fill-up-my-whole-c-drive-windows-installed-drive).

As an aside, this actually saved me a pretty big headache on a laptop lab very recently where I misconfigured the Polybase setup and filled up the dedicated SQL Server drive in a matter of days.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the documentation [SQL Server 2019: Hardware and software requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver15) SQL server is using some space on disk. The exact space depends on the option & features you installed but the space you are missing is in line with the requirements.

Take a look at the folders "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" for 32 bit components like SSMS.